# Regex pattern to identify only one set of curly brackets

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm looking for a regex pattern which will match only one set of curly brackets.
Basically I have a object like this: `{Hello: '${name}'}` and I want a pattern which will only replace the brackets around the variable and not all. The output should be something like: `{Hello: 'name'}` and the value of name can then be inserted. This is the regex that I created: `(\$\{|\})` but it is replacing even the last bracket and outputs something like this: {Hello: 'name'
Can anyone help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is `{Hello: '${name}'}` an object or a string? You last comment makes me think that it's a string.

Comment: I'm stringifying the object before applying regex pattern on it so yes it is a string.

Comment: `.replace(/\$\{(\w+)}/g, '$1')`

Comment: Consider not stringifying the object and doing the replace on the property value itself?

Comment: Also, _how_ are you stringifying? `JSON.stringify` will not produce that output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
.replace(/\$\{(\w+)}/g, '$1')
```

Alternatively:

```js
.replace(/\$\{([^{}]+)}/g, '$1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WcKhyK/2). *Details*:

- `\$\{` - `${` string
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more letters/digits/underscores
- `[^{}]+` - one or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}` - a `}` char.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
console.log("{Hello: '${name}'}".replace(/\$\{(\w+)}/g, '$1'))
```